# Does MicrosoftWebDriver support delete cookie?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here are my code:

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
driver = new EdgeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

it was failed, who knows why?

Comment: EdgeDriver extends RemoteWebDriver which implements the deleteAllCookies() method. EdgeDriver class does not override this method so from the code it should be working.

Comment: it failed in the sense that you got an error or it just did not delete the cookies?

Comment: @DavidBaak i got an error and the cookies did not deleted

Comment: Can you post the error log?